# GNOME like power manager for windows

Tags: windows, gnome, power-management

Is there any tool like GNOME power manager for windows 7. I love all the info it can get us, like battery health and charge/discharge time accuracies.

Free software prefered

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the Gnome power manager, but is something like this what you're looking for?

[Battery care](http://batterycare.bkspot.com/en/index.html)

> shows detailed information about your
>   battery's wear level, capacity, and
>   consumption

[image]

Comment: yeah that handles almost everything, still the graphs are missing, but its good as it is.